# How to use encoded text as a string

Tags: python, python-3.x, encoding, decoding

I want to write an encoded text to a file using Python 3.6, the issue is that I want to write it as a string and not as bytes.

```
text = open(file, 'r').read()
enc = text.encode(encoding)  # for example: "utf-32"
f = open(new_file, 'w')
f.write(str(enc)[2:-1])
f.close()
```

The problem is, I still get the file content as bytes (e.g. the '\n' remains the same instead of become a new row).

I also tried to use:

```
enc.decode(encoding)
```

but it's just returning me back the old text I had in the first place.

any ideas how can I improve this piece of code?

Thanks.

Comment: You can open the file like `open(file, 'r', encoding="your_encoding")` then while you apply `read()` the result will be a binary object you can decode it using `decode("utf32")`

Comment: When I open the file as mentioned, I cannot apply either `read()` or `decode(encoding)`

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have here is that you `encode` into `utf-32` bytes object and then cast it back into a string object without specifying an encoding.  The default is `utf-8`, so you've just converted using the wrong encoding.  If you pass the same encoding to [`str`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str) then it should work.

Better yet, don't call `str` at all when writing out - if you already have a bytes object, it's not necessary.

This concept generally trips up a lot of people.  I suggest reading the explanation [here](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2012/01/30/the-bytesstr-dichotomy-in-python-3) to help wrap your head around how and why we do the string/bytes conversions.  A good rule of thumb - string types inside your python, and decode to string from bytes as data comes in, encode from string to bytes as it goes out.